# batch command copy or move a folder to parent folder as many level/s specified

Tags: batch-file, command, directory, command-line-arguments, parent

My new question is related to my old question i had posted.

I had posted this question

7zip command to extract a folder with path intact to specific folder but excluding parent source path.

i get **"i:\delete\rising\dawn\folder2"**

**Thus a new question aroused.**

i want to copy/move the folder "folder2" to the parent folder 2 level (it means two times to parent folder)

i:\delete\folder2

OR in cases 3 level up.

i:\folder2

i.e. "folder2" shall be copied/moved to upper level (parent folder) the number of times i specify

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The Batch file below move the folder specified in the first parameter as many levels up as the number specified in second parameter:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%a in ("%~1") do set "newPath=%%~DPa" & set "folder=%%~Na"
for /L %%i in (1,1,%2) do for %%a in ("!newPath:~0,-1!") do set "newPath=%%~DPa"
ECHO move "%~1" "%newPath%%folder%"
```

For example, if previous Batch file is named `MoveUp.bat`:

```
MoveUp "i:\delete\rising\dawn\folder2" 2
```

If the `move` command shown is correct, delete the `ECHO` part in order to execute the command.

**EDIT**: *Reply to the comment*

Output example:

```
C:\> MoveUp "i:\delete\rising\dawn\folder2" 2
move "i:\delete\rising\dawn\folder2" "i:\delete\folder2"

C:\> MoveUp "i:\delete\rising\dawn\folder2" 3
move "i:\delete\rising\dawn\folder2" "i:\folder2"
```

Run the program in the same way of the examples above and confirm that you get the same output.

If you get a different output, please post it besides your Windows version.

If you get the same output, please explain why this output does not solve your problem and specify what should be the desired output.

Remember that the program just DISPLAY the command! It does NOT execute it. If you want the program to execute the `move` command, you must delete the `ECHO` part from the last line this way:

```
move "%~1" "%newPath%%folder%"
```

Comment: Excuse me, but "doesn't work" is very vague... See the edit in my answer above.